# Time series prediction for a chaotic multivariate data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, autoregressive

I am trying to forecast a chaotic multivariate time series, and any architecture I use ( LSTM, MLP or tried to implement Autoregression architectures from few papers like https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.02971.pdf /  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07015.pdf) I get straight line as predictions with some noise.

[image]

On using a simple LSTM with LBFGS optimizer, I am able to train the data but my predictions are bad. One thing I notice is my input values are of order e-05 so I scale it up by multiplying it with 10^2 ( otherwise the loss is too low) . I tried pre-processing like MinMax and Standard Scaling which seemed to worsen my performance.

Training with LBFGS and LSTM :
[image]

Testing with LBFGS :
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The time-series that you are trying to predict looks like a random walk -- meaning it does not show a pattern. Hence, I am not surprised that the LSTM is not able to predict the series since there is nothing to 'learn'.

If you want to make sure that your implementation is correct, i recommend you take example data with a strong pattern -- meaning a time-series where you can estimate by eye how it will develop. If your implementation with the new time-series is still random, then at least you know that your implementation has a bug.

Edit: The reason why the training performance looks good is likely overfitting